# Query Parameters for microsoft wsfed common endpoint to login.microsoftonline.com

Tags: azure, ws-federation

I am using Owin `wsFederation` package to do WAAD sign-in on windows azure.

My problem is that I want to pass `id=501358` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf` and I don't know if that's possible. I am redirecting users to `https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed` which again redirects to the `login.microsoftonline.com` but it does not pass query strings along.
Just to make it more clear:

I am redirecting to:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/wsfed?wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fdemo009.s-innovations.net&wctx=blablabla&wreply=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44309%2f&wa=wsignin1.0
```

based on the the `wsFederationMessage`

that gets redirected to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2flogin.windows.net%2fcommon%2fwsfed&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wctx=blablabal
```

I want `&site_id=501358` added to the `login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf` and from my understanding `wctx` is to pass state around to when it comes back to my site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure ACS + Form value storage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280071/azure-acs-form-value-storage)

Comment: Check the answers to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280071/azure-acs-form-value-storage). Especially the second answer, which is not the accepted one.  WS-Federation gives you a "Context" (wctx) parameter which you can use to transfer data around the federation process.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didnt find those. Will test it out tonight if I can make it work also

Comment: If it solves the problem I will close the question

Comment: From reading the other question, it seems they are about getting getting parameters back again from the signin. Note that what I want is to make the wsfed endpoint pass a parameter to the login endpoint (none of them is my services). But i will test ofcause

Comment: you are right that WCTX is to pass a context that you want to keep traversing during the federation. This parameter (wctx) will not be processed by any STS nor Federation Service. As for passing additional query parameters to the STS itself - I am not sure it is possible at all. Is it because of the Customized login page feature of WAAD you want to pass this parameter to the STS (login.microsoftonline.com) ?

Comment: Yes. The default only allows organizational accounts to sign in but if the side_id or id is passed to STS then it let the user select if its a live id or a organizational login. I want that feature also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49216/discussion-between-astaykov-and-pksorensen)