# Redirection after Windows Azure Authentication

Tags: redirect, azure, federated-identity, ws-federation

I built a MVC 4 app with VS2012, WIF and Identity and access tool. I am using Windows azure AD for authentication. My app is registered with windows azure and whenever the authentication is successful, it redirects to the index page. But I want it to redirect to another page which will do further processing of the request.

I am not able to achieve this as windows azure always redirects to the index page. I tried changing the "Reply URL" in the azure management portal but it does nothing. Is there a way I can redirect the page to say /Mycompany/Verify page instead of the home or the index page ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the WS-Federation 'wctx' parameter to pass the redirect URL.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281399/2899711 for more context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I also found out that wctx parameter was used and also, in my case it was hard coded and I hate to change it and that worked ! thanks again !